# How to replace Match value with new value in Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have a string, like this:

```
string str = "id=1,id=2,id=5,id=22";
```

Then, I apply some regex on this string, in order to get the identifiers :

```
var idMatchCollection = regex.Matches(str);

foreach(Match match in idMatchCollection)
{
   var newValue = SomeFunction(match.toString()); 
  // i want to replace newValue for Match which we have in foreach with newValue. That reflect in sting str.
}
```

So, the final output should be like this :

```
str = "id=234,id=576,id=5767,id=756765"
```

`(234,567,5767,756765)` are the values I got by function in the foreach loop `for(1,2,5,22)`

Comment: Do you have a `Dictionary<string, string>`, with keys matching `id`s, that you can use to perform replacements?

Comment: I don't understand ... how looks the input and how output should look ?

Comment: I don't want to use dictionary. I want some different approach that do replace per match.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use the Regex.Replace(String, MatchEvaluator) method which calls your callback function on every match.

Here's a sample from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class RegExSample
{
    static string CapText(Match m)
    {
        // Get the matched string. 
        string x = m.ToString();
        // If the first char is lower case... 
        if (char.IsLower(x[0]))
        {
            // Capitalize it. 
            return char.ToUpper(x[0]) + x.Substring(1, x.Length - 1);
        }
        return x;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "four score and seven years ago";

        System.Console.WriteLine("text=[" + text + "]");

        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\w+");

        string result = rx.Replace(text, new MatchEvaluator(RegExSample.CapText));

        System.Console.WriteLine("result=[" + result + "]");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Regex.Replace` method. Like:

```
string str = "id=1,id=2,id=5,id=22";
var regex = new Regex("[0-9]+");
var replaced = regex.Replace(str, (match) =>
{
  return "x" + match.Value + "x";
});
// replaced will have value of "id=x1x,id=x2x,id=x5x,id=x22x"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could only come up to this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=id\=)\d+");
var str = "id=1,id=2,id=5,id=22";
var coll = new List<string>();
coll.AddRange(new string[] { "234", "567", "5767", "756765" });
var cnt = 0;
var prev_idx = 0;
var output = string.Empty;
for (var match = regex.Match(str); match.Success; match = match.NextMatch())
{
    output += str.Substring(prev_idx, match.Index - prev_idx) + coll[cnt++];
    prev_idx = match.Index + match.Length;
}
// Output: id=234,id=567,id=5767,id=756765
```